# Python Selenium, Drop Down

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I can't get Python to select "Buy" from the drop down menu:

```
<a href="" role="button" aria-pressed="false" class="td-wb-dropdown__item-content" data-ng-click="tdWbDropdownItemController.select()" data-td-wb-transclude=""> <span data-ng-bind="'trading.order.common.ACTION_' + item | translate">Buy</span> </a>
```

My code:

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_class_name('td-wb-dropdown__item-content'))
select.select_by_index(1)
select.select_by_visible_text("Buy")
```

My error:

> Select only works on `<select>` elements, not on `<a>`

Also, I'm able to click on a drop down itself. However, I'm just unsure how to select my option.

```
Tsymbol = browser.find_element_by_class_name('td-wb-dropdown__placeholder') # Clicking on BUY/SELL
Tsymbol.click()
```

Answer (score 3):

Listen to your compiler, **and trust it**. It told you **exactly why** your code does not work. :-)

Don't use `Select(` part. Just find element by class name - use browser's method directly.

Another trick is to find element**s**, and check if any are present (returned list is not empty).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that. I tried many options but i'm stuck. This drop down menu has 2 options "buy" and "sell". However, they have same basic class name "td-wb-dropdown__item-content"

Answer (score 1):

Got it solved, thank you

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Buy']").click();
```

Comment: XPath is flaky.Instead, get list of elements by class, loop over them, and check which one has the desired text, then click on that one.

Comment: As an alternative to the suggestion made by @Peter Masiar, make your xpath more robust: `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='td-wb-dropdown__item-content' and text()='Buy']").click();` In the event that there were many elements on the page with the same class value, getting the full list and iterating through it will hurt performance. Using a more specific xpath with have a minimal effect on performance.

Comment: @shiny, can you please expand this answer to explain why it solved your problem?  It will help others in the future understand how you reached your conclusion